# Server-defined exchanges vs User-defined exchanges

Tags: rabbitmq

Are there any advantages in creating your own exchanges in RabbitMQ?

E.g. using "amq.direct" vs "my_direct_exchange" of type=direct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short:

Yes, they give you freedom to give representative name, set extra options and isolate messages flow from each other when you need that.

## Long:

By default `amq.*` of each type of available exchanges +1 direct without name as a default for publish usage are pre-declared by broker in each vhost, as to [AMQP Specification 1.6. Class exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp-xml-doc0-9-1.pdf).

If you have no special needs *(see explanation below)* and there are separate vhosts for each your project (or you know what you are doing) there are no difference between pre-defined and user-defined one, at least in RabbitMQ implementation.

The benefit of `amq.*` exchanges is they are always pre-defined, so you don't usually need to create them first before publishing.

**Note**, that your app still can delete pre-defined exchanges if they have enough rights.

In addition, `amq.*` entities are aimed for internal usage, especially queues (you can't even declare one starting with `amq.`), so using `amq.*` exchanges different from predefined one (e.g. `amq.rabbitmq.{trace,log}`) from user application may not be good idea at all.

### Special cases when `amq.*` exchanges used

Some plugins utilize `amq.*` exchanges, inc. default ones. For example, [STOMP plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html) uses `amq.topic`, RabbitMQ itself use `amq.rabbitmq.log` for logging, [Firehose Traces](http://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) uses `amq.rabbitmq.trace`. There are may be another plugins which utilize default exchanges, inc. proprietary. Using same exchange with them may lead to unexpected result,  like messages flow intersection.

Also, keep in mind that predefined exchanges are durable by default and has default attributes and flags which may be different from what you really need.

Also, **keep in mind**, RabbitMQ define `amq.match` exchange alongside with `amq.headers`, both `headers` type, so for compatibility between brokers you can't rely on `amq.match` exchange to be defined from the cradle.

When you write some tests for AMQP client you may also use predeclared exchanges (and you probably have no choice).

As you can see, if your need pass under all above then yes, you can use them, but I can suggest that it's not a best practice.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "special needs" ?

Comment: Updated my answer. You can also ask this question on IRC or mailing list or even in twitter (see http://www.rabbitmq.com/contact.html)

Comment: Does the exchange choice somehow affect the performance (as other apps might be using the server-defined exchange) ?

Comment: There are no different between predefined an user-defined queues AFIK. But if your messages flow intersect you may get unexpected messages in your queue which may cause both consumer failure. E.g. you publish to `amq.topic` exchange to queue `fruits` only apples and pears, but some other publish will also utilize `amq.topic` and also send somethng to `fruits`, let say oranges and apricot. As you can see now all four types will be in the same queue. Sometimes (I guess they are rare like Citroen C1 in sport coupe) it's expected behavior, but mostly we use project-specific exchanges and queues.

Comment: Well I had in mind the scenario where the same exchange is used by multiple apps which publish/consume from their respective queues (i.e. different apps use different queues but route through the same exchange).

Comment: You should not worry about performance, RabbitMQ smart enough to use various techniques to minimize route costs. So it less likes that you'll ever have bottleneck in low routing performance.